# Переопределение Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Загрузил картинку Loader'ом, а как её присвоить собственному классу унаследованному от Bitmap не знаю :) Может нужно что то override'ть?

```
var _bm:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content as Bitmap);
var _bmd:BitmapData = _bm.bitmapData;
var _map:UBitmap = new UBitmap(_bmd);
addChild(_map);

public class UBitmap extends Bitmap 
{
    public function UBitmap(bitmapData:BitmapData=null, pixelSnapping:String="auto", smoothing:Boolean=false) 
    {
        super(bitmapData, pixelSnapping, smoothing);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде так.

```
var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(_loader.content);

var bitmap:BitmapData = image.bitmapdata;
```

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо Вам! Спасибо Вам ещё раз, разобрался.
var _map:UBitmap = new UBitmap(event.target.content.bitmapData as BitmapData);

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь.